# How to search for expiring emails on Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

My workplace introduced a retention policy on emails. Now they are set to expire after a certain period (4 months). So I would like to be able to search for these emails which are close to expire (say, within the next week)

I try to search for them with a custom criteria but Outlook does not show me any! (despite the fact that there are a lot of them set to expire within the next week)

I tried to search for any email that is to expire but still the search returns naught:

[image]

How can I search for emails that are going to be expired within the next week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your organization has very likely implemented the policy on the Exchange server. Therefore your Outlook desktop client's idea of which messages are due to expire may not tally.

Instead, you may use the Received field.

I'm using Outlook 365 subscription edition, and the appearance of this dialog differs from yours, but the arrangement at the bottom is the same. By clicking the Field dropdown, you can choose Date/Time fields and select Received:

[image]

To identify emails expiring soon, choose a date based on your organization's current expiry policy. For example, if  emails expire after 4 months, choose a date a little under 4 months in the past. Use other date/time fields in your criteria as required, such as "Sent on or before" to show your Sent emails that are about to expire.

Comment: thanks. though one more thing: would it be possible to use smth like -4 months from the current date instead of specifying a date?

Comment: @şaloma for more fine-graned control like this, you may customize Outlook using VBA among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Search Date Range in Microsoft Outlook Using Advanced Find Feature may be helpful to you.

1. Choose the folder where you have to search emails by the date range. Place the cursor on the Instant Search box to enable Search Tools. Then, you have to select Search, followed by Search Tools and then Advanced Find.
2. The Advanced Find dialog box will open up on the screen. Navigate to the Advanced tab.
3. Click on Fields, then All Mail fields and then select the option Received.
4. Choose the between option from the drop-down menu of condition.
5. In the Value box, enter the date range in the format like the screenshot
6. Press on the Add to List button.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need more fine-grained control than is provided by the standard features of the Outlook UI, you may customize Outlook's behaviour by writing some VBA code or an Outlook add-in.

You can add as many Outlook customizations as you like, and they can be as simple as a VBA event handler macro that pops up a message to remind you about something after you press Send, ranging through VBA routines that search your calendar and mail for items meeting certain criteria, to [ribbon customizations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31) and [add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins-overview).

It is also possible to create custom mail search filters using the
[Jet and DAV Searching and Locating (DASL) syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Search-and-Filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison); however, I don't recommend this as a starting-point. It is a specialized area and you may find it more straightforward to ignore it, at least initially, and deal directly with mail item properties in VBA routines in the first instance.

The following links should help you to get started using VBA:

[VBA samples at slipstick.com](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook-developers/vba-samples/)

[VBA samples at vboffice.net](http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/)

[Microsoft Outlook VBA reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook)